# Read GPIO status from server

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, gpio, windowsiot

I have a raspberry PI install on a client (with windows iot OS).
My question is how can I access remotely to **Pin Status** of RPI from another client?

I installed **PIGPIO** to connect remotely with **IP** and **port**

```
PiGPIO.PigsClient piClient= new PiGPIO.PigsClient("192.168.1.36", 5463);
await piClient.ConnectAsync();
if (piClient.IsConnected)
            {
                piClient.READ(6); //pin number
            }
```

*but port is not open on RPI*.

What is the best solution on this case?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

if you want to connect to a Windows IoT Core raspberry-pi computer and wish to control GPIO remotely over the internet, you could download [w3pi.info](https://w3pi.info) web-server and download the [flipled](https://w3pi.info/www/_static/bin/flipled.zip) atl server (visual c++) sample 
(requires raspberry pi 2). The flipled sample is configured to read the LED light on the raspberry pi 2 board, but you could re-code the sample to use a different pin number.